# Exit out of c program without use of exit()

Tags: c, exit

Is there anyway to exit out of a c program without using exit(0)? I'm working on a assignment and I'm not allowed to link with any libraries so that means no lib.c :(

Comment: Use a return statement.

Comment: Any return statement in main() causes the program to end.

Comment: To make it clear: you have to exit a program and you don't have access to the main function?

Comment: I don't have access to main. I can only edit one file and it doesn't have main in it (main calls functions in my file).

Comment: int *p = 0; *p = 1; That should do it.

Comment: If possible, append some part of your file in your question so we can take a look at it. :-)

Comment: If you just return or drop out of your function, then it will return to main which will return or drop out.

Comment: There's a very strong likelihood that your program is implicitly linked with the standard C library. This means that just declaring `exit` might be enough to get access to it: `void exit(int);` This might run counter to the spirit of your assignment, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can just `return` from `main()` (normally at the end to keep code readable, but could be anywhere)

Comment: I don't know where the entry point to my program is. I can only edit one file and it doesnt have main in it.

Comment: @user2756569 what does that file look like?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you can't use a library and can't just return from main, you could do something that's not really recommended: try to access a null pointer or perform a divide-by-zero error.  That will technically end the program.

Comment: lol (blank spaces don't count as characters here on comments)

Comment: I get the right answer with my out files with this approach, but it makes all the tests abort for the grading script so i get a 0 bc the tests fail rofl